# Angular and ngrx: removing tap() causes compilation errors

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, compiler-errors, ngrx

I have a piece of code (slightly simplified) that works properly and console logs show everything correctly, the passed parameters are valid (and not empty):

```
  return observable.pipe(map(response => ({ response, param2, param3, param4, param5 })));
}),
tap(({ response }) => {
  if (this.hasNotifications(response?.notif)) {
    //do something
  }
}),
filter(({ response }) => !this.hasNotifications(response?.notif)),
tap(() => console.log('we are here')),
switchMap(({ response, param2, param3, param4, param5 }) => {
  console.log('and even here');
  console.log(response);
  console.log(param2);
  console.log(param3);
  console.log(param4);
  console.log(param5);
```

Unfortunately, if I remove

```
tap(() => console.log('we are here')),
```

as it was inserted for dev purposes only, I'm unable to compile successfully because of the errors:

```
   error TS2339: Property 'param2' does not exist on type '{ response: any; }'.

305     switchMap(({ response, param2, param3, param4, param5 }) => {
```

and the same for param3, param4, param5.

Any ideas why errors started happening and how to fix them so the parameters still passed properly?

Comment: can you share the full pipe?

Comment: @TobiasS, unfortunately, no. But I can't even imagine any reasons.

Comment: any chance that you have more then 9 operators in the pipe with the `tap` and exactly 9 without it?

Comment: @TobiasS. Twelve. Do you think it's like here https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/4221 and your suggestion would be to pass all { response, param2, param3, param4, param5 }  instead of just one { response } for tap(({ response }) and filter(({ response }) as tap(({ response, param2, param3, param4, param5}) and filter(({ response, param2, param3, param4, param5}) ?  With another words, to update two strings above by adding missed parameters?

Comment: @TobiasS.  switchMap(({ response, param2, param3, param4, param5 }) => was the tenth operator with tap and ninth without that removed tap.

Comment: Yes, the 9 pipe operator limit is most cerainly what is happening here. The error you are getting is probably correct and was hidden by the limit before.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this code is for Reducer or Effect that emitted by Action that pass many parameters (as properties object). If so then you can solve the problem by replacing the parameter object: { response, param2, param3, param4, param5 } to be only 'response' and then get all the parameters as members in the object 'response' as following:

```
switchMap((response) => {
  console.log('and even here');
  console.log(response);
  console.log(response.param2);
  console.log(response.param3);
  console.log(response.param4);
  console.log(response.param5);
}
```